# OpenShift environment variable from secret

Tags: openshift, setenv

I have some environment variables in OpenShift that reference a secret. I can add these variables in the deployment config by editing the yaml deployment file. However, is there any way to set environment variables by referencing a secret using the `oc env`  command?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

Run:

```
oc set env --help
```

One of the examples is:

```
oc set env --from=secret/mysecret dc/myapp
```

Note that `oc env` is deprecated and you should use `oc set env`.

Comment: Hi, I did that, but I received an error: Error: unknown flag: --from. Could it be that I have an old version of the oc tool?

Comment: Most likely. What do you get for ``oc version``? So what ``oc`` client version and also what OpenShift cluster version?

Comment: Example incorrect because it is not full (have not all parameters) and in consequence it is not work.